# new line in for multiplcatoin (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am new to python and I am trying to essentially "draw a board game", however I need it to print new lines with multiplication. This is my code so far:

```
x=int(input("How many columns? "))

y=int(input("How many rows? "))    
z="|"
q="---"

f=((z + q)*x)+z


print(f*y)
```

What I want is to have newlines between rows, like this:

```
|---|---|---| 

|---|---|---| 

|---|---|---|
```

I tried:

```
print('\n', f,'\n', f, '\n', f)
```

How to put newlines between rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want spaces between rows, you can do:

```
print("\n\n".join([f]*y))
```

Upon decomposing:

- `[f] * y` yields an array of rows
- `string.join(list)` puts a string between each element in an list

So, you get two new lines between each row.

Comment: Thank you so much!